# PLSQL decode NVARCHAR2 from BASE64 to UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, plsql, oracle12c

I have a database which stores usernames only in English at the moment.

I would like to incorporate ***`BASE64`*** & ***`UTF-8`*** in order to store in other languages as well; I want to store it in a column of type `NVARCHAR2`.

The database procedure receives the name in `BASE64`, I'm decoding it via `UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE` & converting the string to `VARCHAR2` using `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2`. But I get gibberish back and not the actual word.

For example I get **'алекс'** as the name in `BASE64`. I'm able to decode it but the cast to `VARCHAR2/NVARCHAR2` does not return the value: I get only gibberish.

I'm running on `Oracle 12c` using ***`NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1`***

Here is the code I use to decode:

```
DECLARE 
  lv_OrgUserName VARCHAR2(2000);
  lv_encodedUserName VARCHAR2(2000);
  lv_UserName    VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN 

lv_OrgUserName := 'алекс';
lv_encodedUserName := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(lv_OrgUserName)));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (lv_encodedUserName);
lv_UserName := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (lv_encodedUserName)));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (lv_UserName);

END;
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: I confirm your code: it works for "normal chars", like `abc`, but not for exotic ones from your example.

Comment: @J.Chomel, OK, how can I get it to work for exotic ones?

Comment: I did a lot of research today, and I couldn't overcome it. I read somewhere that this could come from your client that isn't set correctly to handle greek chars. Thus DBMS_OUTPUT will never be able to output a greek chars, no matter how hard you try. But that's not final, since I don't understand it quite well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost WE8ISO8859P1 (Western European 8-bit ISO 8859 Part 1, or - ISO8859 Part 1) does not support cyryllic characters:
see this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Therefore if you try to store a string like `алекс` into **VARCHAR2** variable/column, you will always get `a????` as an outcome.

Probably during the database installation someone has not considered cyryllic characters and has choosen a bad codepage.
A better option is ISO/IEC 8859-5 (part 5), see this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-5

One option is to change this encoding - but this is not easy and it is beyound of this question.

---

What you can do is to strictly use **NVARCHAR2** datatype instead of **VARCHAR2** datatype in all places of your application that must support cyrillic characters.
There are still some pitfalls though you need to be aware of:

- You cannot use `DBMS_OUTPUT` package to debug your code, because this package support only VARCHAR2 datatype, it doesn't support NVARCHAR
- you must use `N'some string'` literals (with N prefix) in all literals --> `'алекс'` is of VARCHAR2 datatype and it is always automatically converted to `'a????'` in your encoding, while `n'алекс'` is of NVARCHAR2 datatype and such conversion doesn't occur.

---

The below code is tested on version 12c, I am using `EE8MSWIN1250` code page (it also desn't support cyrillic characters):

```
select * from nls_database_parameters
where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET%';

PARAMETER                VALUE
-----------------------  ------------
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET   AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET         EE8MSWIN1250
```

please give it a try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_base64 AS
   FUNCTION BASE64_ENCODE( str nvarchar2 ) RETURN varchar2;
   FUNCTION BASE64_DECODE( str varchar2  ) RETURN nvarchar2;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_base64 AS

   FUNCTION BASE64_ENCODE( str nvarchar2 ) RETURN varchar2
   IS 
     lv_encodedUserName VARCHAR2(2000);
   BEGIN
    lv_encodedUserName := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(str)));
    RETURN lv_encodedUserName;
   END;


   FUNCTION BASE64_DECODE( str  varchar2  ) RETURN nvarchar2
   IS
     lv_UserName    nVARCHAR2(2000);
   BEGIN
      lv_UserName := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_nVARCHAR2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (str)));
      RETURN lv_UserName;
   END;

END;
/
```

A few examples:

```
select 'aлекс' As A, n'aлекс' As B from dual;

A     B   
----- -----
a???? aлекс
```

---

```
select my_base64.BASE64_ENCODE( n'аaaлекс' ) As aleks from dual;

ALEKS                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BDAAYQBhBDsENQQ6BEE=
```

---

```
select my_base64.BASE64_DECODE( 'BDAAYQBhBDsENQQ6BEE=' ) as aleks from dual;

ALEKS                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
аaaлекс
```

---

```
select my_base64.BASE64_DECODE( my_base64.BASE64_ENCODE( n'аaaлекс' ) ) as Aleks from dual;

ALEKS                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
аaaлекс
```

Comment: Brilliant. Works the same on Oracle11g.