# Oracle PLSQL equivalent of ASCIISTR(N'str')

Tags: oracle, unicode, plsql

My database has `NLS_LANGUAGE:AMERICAN / NLS_CHARACTERSET:WE8ISO8859P15 / NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET:AL16UTF16`; `NLS_LANG` is set to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252` in my *Windows> properties> advanced system settings> advanced> environment variables* - hope it applies to my PLSQL Dev.

I use `ASCIISTR` to get a unicode encoded value for exotic chars like this:

```
SELECT ASCIISTR(N'κόσμε') FROM DUAL;
```

Results in

```
ASCIISTR(UNISTR('\03BA\1F79\03...
---------------------------------
\03BA\1F79\03C3\03BC\03B5
```

It looks like the '`N`' means the string is unicode, because if I don't specify it I get it wrong encoded.

```
SELECT ASCIISTR('κόσμε') FROM DUAL;
```

Results in

```
ASCIISTR('??SµE')
--------------------
??s\00B5e
```

### What does this '`N`' stands for? How do I invoke it in PLSQL?

I intend to use it on a pl/sql variable to encode exotice characters like this:

```
DECLARE 
  l_in VARCHAR2(2000);
  l_ec VARCHAR2(2000);
  l_dc VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN 
  l_in := 'κόσμε';
  execute immediate 'select ASCIISTR(N'''||l_in||''') from dual'  into l_ec;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_ec);

  select unistr(l_ec) into l_dc from dual;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_dc);
END;
```

But I get

```
??s\00B5e
??sµe
```

As if I were in the second case above, without the '`N`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`N'κόσμε'` is (more or less) equivalent to `CAST('κόσμε' AS NVARCHAR2(..))`

With `N'κόσμε'` you say "treat the string as NVARCHAR". If you write just `'κόσμε'` then the string is treated as `VARCHAR`. However, your `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is `WE8ISO8859P15` which does not support Greek characters. Thus you get `?` as placeholder.

You didn't tell us your `NLS_NCHARACTERSET` setting, most likely this supports Unicode.

btw, you don't have to `select ... from dual`, simply write like

```
l_ec := ASCIISTR('κόσμε');
```

in PL/SQL.

What is your **local** `NLS_LANG` value, i.e. at your client side? Most likely it does not match the character encoding of your SQL*Plus. See this answer for more details: [OdbcConnection returning Chinese Characters as "?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600)

Comment: `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET:AL16UTF16` ; Shame on me, I don't know how to get this NLS_LANG from PLSQL Developper.

Comment: I think my `NLS_LANG` is `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252` (from windows env. variables)

Comment: The default codepage set of your `cmd.exe` is (most likely) 850, which does not match `WE8MSWIN1252`. Note, SQL*Plus inherits the codepage settings form parent cmd.exe. They have to match. Btw, here is a solution to change the default codepage of your cmd.exe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/33475373#33475373

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change registry in here. I'll try by changing NLS_LANG

Answer (score 0):

I (sadly) discovered in [PLSQL decode NVARCHAR2 from BASE64 to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907398/plsql-decode-nvarchar2-from-base64-to-utf-8) that ***`DBMS_OUTPUT` doesn't support `NVARCHAR2` datatype***.  I thusly can't use it to debug.

Then I can do the following to test:

```sql
-- encoding
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_ec(l_in nvarchar2) RETURN varchar2 is
    l_out varchar2(32000);
BEGIN    
    l_out := asciistr(l_in);
    return l_out;  
END;
/

-- decoding
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_dc(l_in varchar2) RETURN nvarchar2 is
    l_out nvarchar2(32000);
BEGIN 
    l_out := unistr(l_in);
    return l_out;
END;
/
```

with expected result!

```
select my_ec(N'κόσμε') from dual;
--'\03BA\1F79\03C3\03BC\03B5'
select my_dc('\03BA\1F79\03C3\03BC\03B5') from dual;
--'κόσμε'
select my_dc(my_ec(N'κόσμε')) from dual;
--'κόσμε'
```