# NCHAR with UTF8 doesn´t set up correct czech words using file

Tags: sql, oracle, utf-8, nchar

I would like to ask you help regarding one thing or just your point of view.

We have script in PL/SQL that worked correctly. But now when I want to run it, it doesn´t set up correctly czech words like (`ěščěščěřěščřěš`).

I read here in stackoverflow to add `NCHAR` in front of code so I did and It works only when I put this code directly into Toad for Oracle to console. But when I want to upload/run this script per our application then we see *????* instead of correct letters.

I have checked many times UTF-8, I switched between many codings and tested I tried in notepad, PSPadd and nothing works. So this must have something to do with coding properties of this file right?

> insert statement

```
INSERT INTO OUR_TABLE ( Client_No, Contact_Type, 
Postal_Code, Address) Values ('999999','TTT','CZ',RPAD(N'Vladimír 
Müller', 35) ||RPAD(N'Kovozal s.r.o.', 35) || RPAD(N'Zálší 74', 35) || 
RPAD(N'565 01 Zálší', 35));
```

Old script worked fine without `N` (`NCHAR`). But now not. I don´t think that there is another solution than just ask maybe some Oracle admin??

I repeat that `N` and `RPAD` works find within the console but admins are not allowed to run this script in console: they have to receive data as file.

What would you do?

Comment: I had similar issue in the past (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923536/oracle-plsql-equivalent-of-asciistrnstr).
Check your **local** `NLS_LANG` value, i.e. at your client side. Most likely it does not match the character encoding of your SQL*Plus. See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600

Comment: Hi J.Chomel I have checked and it shows me UTF16....

Comment: We have changed our NLS_LAND to UTF8 and it works now. SOLVED. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Clients in UNIX and in TOAD are different. You were using a different `NLS_LANG` (*UTF16*) in your IDE, which made you *believe* it was displaying wrong chars.

#### So Solution was to change `NLS_LANG` to *UTF8* in your IDE.